# How to automatically import .scss files from project or from directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sass, webpack

I am working on a Reactjs application. I am using Webpack.
My goal is to be able create a component, and create a .scss file with the styling for that component in the same directory.

e.g.:

```
|- components/
|           |-- component1.js
|           |-- component1.scss (automatically import files like this one!)
|
|- main.scss (gets loaded by webpack by default)
```

What do I need to do in order to be able to automatically import the .scss files without the need of doing an @import in the main.scss file every time a new file is created. I would be acceptable to import all files within a given directory. If I create a new .scss, it should automatically be added to the styles on build. I do not care about the order of import.
Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-glob-loader.

Globbing, or glob loading, will let you write `@import "components/**/*"` type declarations and grab all .scss files like in the Rails asset pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to directly tell sass to import everything in a directory. JustH's glob loader adds this functionality.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is to modify the path in the gulpfile.js if you're using Gulp to build your app.

Follow the steps on this blog : http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/425/automatic-import-of-lesssass-files-with-gulp

Comment: They said they were using webpack, not gulp.